# Show $f$ is constant given $g=\overline{f}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-riemann-equations

> I am trying to show that if $f$ and $g=\overline{f}$ are both differentiable in a domain, then $f$ is constant on that domain.

My attempt:
Let $$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
$$g(z)=r(x,y)+is(x,y)$$
Equating real and imaginary parts, we can see that $$u(x,y)=r(x,y) \ \ \ (1)$$ $$v(x,y)=-s(x,y) \ \ \ (2)$$
So we want to show that $u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$.
How can I show this?

I have tried differentiating $(1), (2)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ to utilise the CR equations, but I have not shown the desired result.

Comment: You have $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and $\bar{f}(x,y)=u(x,y)-iv(x,y)$. Can you finish from there?

Comment: Not really. Equating the real and imaginary parts will yield the same as $(1)$ and $(2)$ above. I'm unsure of how to use the CR equations to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CR equations for $f$ give $u_x=v_y$; the CR equations for $g$ give $r_x=s_y$. Combining this with $u=r$ and $v=-s$ gives $u_x=v_y=-v_y$. Thus we must have $u_x=v_y=0$.

See if you can use a similar technique to derive $u_y=v_x=0$.

Comment: Ah I see. $u_x$ must be equal be to $0$ as the only $v_y$ that satisfies $u_x=v_y=-v_y$ is $v_y=0$?

Comment: @Bell Yup. Straightforward algebraic manipulation can take you from $v_y=-v_y$ to $v_y=0$

Comment: Yep. I have shown that $u_y=-v_x=v_x$, hence the result.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x+\jmath y) &=& u(x,y) + \jmath v(x,y)
\end{eqnarray*}

where $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are real functions of two inputs $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations are,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &=& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &=& -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{eqnarray*}

SInce $ g\triangleq f^{\star}$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x+\jmath y) &=& u(x,y) + \jmath v(x,y) \\
g(x+\jmath y) &=& u(x,y) - \jmath v(x,y)
\end{eqnarray*}

The CR then will takes us to,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &=& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &=& -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &=& -\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &=& \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

This is satisfied when
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &=& 0\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} &=& 0\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &=&0 \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &=&0\\
\end{eqnarray*}

That is, $f$ (and $g$) are constants.